# Printing to Tkinter Window and not to the program output box (e.g. PyCharm)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am still relatively new to python.

```
def show_entry_fields():
    print("Insert Link/URL:  %s" % (e1.get()))
```

I'm looking for a way to make this "show command" (it displays something previously entered in an input field) not appear in the prompt box of PyCharm but in the tkinter window. How exactly do I set this up?
Because the command print only gives the output in the box in the program.

Comment: `print` is only able to write text to the console or to a file. You need to create a Tkinter gui element such as a label or textbox, add that to your Tkinter window, and set its text in your method. How to do that in your specific case is heavily dependend on the exact goal and the rest of your code. However, most Tkinter tutorials should teach the required basics in their first few paragraphs, so I'd recommend you look at a few tutorials.

Comment: Now I know what to look for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print will not work here. You will have to read the documentation for tkinter: https://python.readthedocs.io/en/v2.7.2/library/tkinter.html

Essentially what you have to do is, you have to make a master element and than a text element inside it. Tkinter is very popular and there are many tutorials online. These tutorials would be better than anyone here explaining to you because you can learn based on your requirements for you project. Here is an example tutorial from https://likegeeks.com/python-gui-examples-tkinter-tutorial/#Get-input-using-Entry-class-Tkinter-textbox
This is probably what you are looking for. Although, I would suggest reading the article if nothing else.

```
from tkinter import *

`window = Tk()

window.title("Welcome to LikeGeeks app")

window.geometry('350x200')

lbl = Label(window, text="Hello")

lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

txt = Entry(window,width=10)

txt.grid(column=1, row=0)

def clicked():

    res = "Welcome to " + txt.get()

    lbl.configure(text= res)

btn = Button(window, text="Click Me", command=clicked)

btn.grid(column=2, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Another good resource that I would suggest is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4McKSuuUQ-0

If you have more time and aare looking into tkinter in a more in-depth fashion check out the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXPyB4XeYLA